# Collect all the PDF in the subdirectories into a specific directory

Tags: copy-paste

Suppose that there is a tree directory `main`, and there are some subdirectories in `main`, e.g., `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`, etc. And there is a specific subdirectory named `PDFs` in `main`. How can I efficiently (maybe by writing a batch file) collect all the PDF in the subdirectories `sub<i>` and copy them into `PDFs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, run

```
cd main
find sub1 sub2 sub3 -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/PDF \;
```

If the target directory is not within `main` you can also skip `cd main` and run `find main -type f ...` instead.

PS: If you want to move the files, use `mv` instead of `cp`. If you want have them in both places but not use twice the disk space, use `ln` to create hard links (two directory entries pointing to the same file).

Comment: If there are too many `sub<i>` directories, is there a method that I do not need to list them all in the terminal command?@nohillside

Comment: @stephen Make sure the target directory is outside of the parent folder and run the command directly on the parent.